# Ubuntu refuses my stored wifi password and I can't enter a new one

Tags: networking, wireless, password

I cannot connect to my home network with Ubuntu. My home network is protected with a password. Every time I enter my password to connect, Ubuntu rejects the attempt and keeps showing another code -- which seems to have been remembered by the system and it appears unable to accept a new password.

I managed to connect to other wifi's.

I also have Windows on the same computer and it connects to my home network with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the profile file for that network which will be stored in /etc/NetworkManager or 
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections then delete the profile in Network Manager itself. Reboot, and then create a new profile for your home WiFi.

There is a possibility your computer's WiFi adapter is not compatible with the type of network broadcast by the home WiFi Router, so if the above fails, please use another computer to find out if your home WiFi is 802.11b, 802.11a, 802.11g, 802.11n or 802.11ac, and also tell us the make and model of your computer as well as the make and model of its WiFi adapter, and the version of Ubuntu you are using.